# Plug-in Development error

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am learning Plug-in Development in Eclipse and have decided to follow the tutorials on Vogella (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#top) However, I am getting an error in my console as soon as I right click on the project and select 'run as eclipse application' (4.2 in the tutorial).

Here is the error:

```
!SESSION 2014-11-19 10:58:22.636 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_NZ
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data \\engad.foe.auckland.ac.nz\engdfs\Home\dgop507\workspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file://engad.foe.auckland.ac.nz/engdfs/Home/dgop507/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2014-11-19 10:58:36.043
!MESSAGE /icons/sample.gif
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /icons/sample.gif
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.bundleentry.Handler.findBundleEntry(Handler.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.BundleResourceHandler.openConnection(BundleResourceHandler.java:169)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLConnection.connect(PlatformURLConnection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLConnection.getURLAsLocal(PlatformURLConnection.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.LocalResourceManager.allocate(LocalResourceManager.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceManager.createImage(ResourceManager.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.getImage(HandledContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.updateIcons(HandledContributionItem.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.update(HandledContributionItem.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.fill(HandledContributionItem.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$3.handleEvent(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at
```

When I remove icon= "icons/sample.gif" from build.properties, I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/icons/eview16/task-list.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLHandler.openConnection(PlatformURLHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.url.URLStreamHandlerProxy.openConnection(URLStreamHandlerProxy.java:114)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImageFromURI(SWTPartRenderer.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImage(SWTPartRenderer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.createTab(StackRenderer.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.processContents(LazyStackRenderer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

I'm not sure if this is to do with my configuration/workspace settings. Any help would be much appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Right from your error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /icons/sample.gif
```

Your plug-in can't find the icons directory or the sample.gif file.

Make sure your icons directory is in the plug-in classpath.

Comment: where would I find this directory?

Comment: @user3254893: I hope the icons directory is somewhere in your plug-in workspace.

Comment: Is it possible to rename the icon?

Comment: To do this: In Eclipse, right click on Project in the Package Explorer > Properties > Java  Build Path > Source > Add Folder... > Select the "icons" folder > OK.

Then relaunch your plugin: Run as  "Eclipse application"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that Exception is that your Plug-In is deployed and is looking for resources in a referenced path, that can not be found.
try something like creating an Image and set the path to the icons according to the path of that class...

Something like this: `new Image(yourDisplay, getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/your-icon.png"))`

and this should work fine!